# time complexity for matrix function

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

I Wrote the function search Matrix to check if the given value is included in the matrix in O(N) time. This matrix has the following properties:•Integers in each row are sorted in ascending from left to right.•Integers in each column are sorted in ascending from top to bottom

```
public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
        if(matrix==null || matrix.length==0 || matrix[0].length==0) 
            return false;

        int m = matrix.length;
        int n = matrix[0].length;

        int start = 0;
        int end = m*n-1;

        while(start<=end){
            int mid=(start+end)/2;
            int midX=mid/n;
            int midY=mid%n;

            if(matrix[midX][midY]==target) 
                return true;

            if(matrix[midX][midY]<target){
                start=mid+1;
            }else{
                end=mid-1;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

•For example,   Consider the following matrix:

```
[[1, 4, 7, 11, 15], 
[2, 5, 8, 12, 19], 
[3, 6, 9, 16, 22], 
[10, 13, 14, 17, 24], 
[18, 21, 23, 26, 30]]
```

Given target=5, return true.
Given target=20, return false.

the code works as expect but i want know does this code have time complexity of O(N).if not what changes should i make to get O(N).

Comment: it is O(logN) because every iteration divides problems space 2 times

Comment: aside note: imagine that `start` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `end` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - what is the value of `(start+end)/2`? don't answer from the top of your head, code/compile/run.

Comment: what should i do to get this into O(N).

Comment: side note2: check what your function returns for 18